# TSQL get id of the lowest value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I need to get the minimun from a group (MIN function) but also its associated id.

```
SELECT
    pv.id,
    MIN(pv.auto)+MIN(a.autonomia) as autonomia,
    -->> a.id as minid
from @autonomie a
join VARDB v on a.id=v.IDARTICO
join RIDIBA r on v.id=r.IDVARDB and r.idartico IS NOT NULL
join @PvTable pv on pv.id=r.IDARTICO
group by pv.id
```

Here I calculate the selected field `autonomia` by `MIN(a.autonomia)`, but I would like to select also the id (a.id field) associate with the lowest getted `a.autonomia` field.

Comment: Do you mean `MIN(a.id)`? or that id that has `MIN(pv.auto)+MIN(a.autonomia)`? in this case you can't do this with `group by pv.id` in the same query.

Comment: Sounds as if you want the min value of each id, you can use `MIN(pv.auto + a.autonomia) OVER (PARTITION BY id)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
SELECT  pv.id
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pv.id ORDER BY pv.auto) pv_auto
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pv.id ORDER BY a.autonomia) a_autonomia
        , a.id a_id
        , pv.auto
        , a.autonomia
INTO    #temp
FROM    @autonomie a
JOIN    VARDB v ON a.id=v.IDARTICO
JOIN    RIDIBA r ON v.id=r.IDVARDB and r.idartico IS NOT NULL
JOIN    @PvTable pv ON pv.id=r.IDARTICO

SELECT  temp_pv_auto.id
        , temp_pv_auto.auto + temp_a_autonomia.autonomia AS autonomia
        , temp_a_autonomia.a_id
FROM    #temp temp_pv_auto
JOIN    #temp temp_a_autonomia ON 
        temp_pv_auto.id = temp_a_autonomia.id
AND     temp_pv_auto.pv_auto = 1 
AND     temp_a_autonomia.a_autonomia = 1
```

You can also try this query:

```
SELECT  pv.id
        , MIN(pv.auto) pv_auto_min
        , MIN(a.autonomia) a_autonomia_min
INTO    #temp
FROM    @autonomie a
JOIN    VARDB v ON a.id=v.IDARTICO
JOIN    RIDIBA r ON v.id=r.IDVARDB and r.idartico IS NOT NULL
JOIN    @PvTable pv ON pv.id=r.IDARTICO
GROUP BY
        pv.id


SELECT  pv.id
        , #temp.pv_auto_min + #temp.a_autonomia_min AS autonomia
        , a.id a_id
FROM    @autonomie a
JOIN    VARDB v ON a.id=v.IDARTICO
JOIN    RIDIBA r ON v.id=r.IDVARDB and r.idartico IS NOT NULL
JOIN    @PvTable pv ON pv.id=r.IDARTICO
JOIN    #temp ON 
        #temp.id = pv.id
AND     #temp.a_autonomia_min = a.autonomia
```

Comment: I abort the query after 8minutes ... the original query takes about 3 sec.

Comment: OK, I kicked out the CTE, it should be faster now, if not, I'll rewrite it again without `ROW_NUMBER` and `PARTITION BY`. Can you try it again?

Comment: I added another query, can you try it?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  pv.id,
    MIN(pv.auto)+MIN(a.autonomia) as autonomia,
    (
        SELECT a2.id from @autonomie a2
            join VARDB v2 on a2.id=v2.IDARTICO
            join RIDIBA r2 on v2.id=r2.IDVARDB and r2.idartico IS NOT NULL
            join @PvTable pv2 on pv2.id=r2.IDARTICO 
        where a2.autonomia = MIN(a.autonomia)
    )
    -->> a.id as minid
from @autonomie a
join VARDB v on a.id=v.IDARTICO
join RIDIBA r on v.id=r.IDVARDB and r.idartico IS NOT NULL
join @PvTable pv on pv.id=r.IDARTICO
group by pv.id
```

Updated to reflect all conditions in subquery.

Comment: Your subquery ignore joins restriction, MIN(a.autonomia) is not getting the minimun from whole autonomia table, but the result of this table in join with VARDB RIDIBA and PvTable.

Comment: If there is more than one record returned from subquery (that is, more than one row in @autonomie.autonomia has a value of `MIN(a.autonomia)`), error `Subquery returned more than 1 value` will occur.

Comment: @Tobia, you'd change the subquery accordingly. So make it have the same conditions/joins. I'm not sure how else you'd do this without a subquery column but I'd be interested to see.

Comment: @Ivang From reading his requirement it sounds like it should be one to one. If there are many ID's to show for one autonomia then it's quite a different question.

Comment: So then you're asking for multiple a.id fields per min(a.autonomia)? If not my theory is correct just needs more in the subquery. Have updated it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure I understood the requirements, but you might try with a subquery:

```
SELECT
    ,pv.id
    ,(MIN(pv.auto) + autonomie_min.autonomia) as autonomia
    ,autonomie_min.id as autonomia_id
from 
  VARDB v
    JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            a.id
            ,MIN(a.autonomia) as autonomia
        FROM
            @autonomie a
        GROUP BY
            a.id
    ) AS autonomie_min ON
        (autonomie_min.id = v.IDARTICO)
    JOIN
    RIDIBA r ON
        (r.IDVARDB = v.id) AND
        (r.idartico IS NOT NULL)
    JOIN
    @PvTable pv ON
        (pv.id = r.IDARTICO)
GROUP BY
    pv.id
```

Subquery *autonomie_min* will produce a table with all the minimum values of *autonomia* associated with each id.

Answer (score -1):

After grouping values you can order the result set and get top 1 from resul set.

```
SELECT TOP 1
pv.id,
MIN(pv.auto)+MIN(a.autonomia) as autonomia,
-->> a.id as minid
from @autonomie a
join VARDB v on a.id=v.IDARTICO
join RIDIBA r on v.id=r.IDVARDB and r.idartico IS NOT NULL
join @PvTable pv on pv.id=r.IDARTICO
group by pv.id
ORDER BY autonomia
```

Comment: No, I'm sorry, i need the a.id (not pv.id) selected by Min(a.autonomia)